# FOR loop in C for specified i values

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a FOR loop in c with specific i values for example i=2,6,8,12,16,20,22,26,34.. I just don't know how to specify increments as they are not equal. This code is not good for me.

```
for (i=2,i<=30,i++) {

}
```

Maybe with specified array of values in i and then run for loop with reference to that array?

Any help?

Comment: Yep - you've already thought of one approach for this (iterating through an array of values). So what are you asking?

Comment: If you´d specify how the increments are computed, one could suggest very specific solutions. For example, I don't see why you'd use a for loop if the value you want to increment with varies except for the case where the loop counter is an index into an array of increments. Then, however, you'll have to initialize the array first, and depending on the code for that, it might make sense to compute the increments on the fly in the (possibly for) loop and drop the init-and-use-array concept altogether.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through an array that contains values of `i` or try to use this list as index to iterate through a different array using list of `i` as index?

Comment: thanks guys I just realised that I have a specified number of values with constant amount which is not going to vary therefore an array[10] seems to be the most appropriate and then run FOR loop for each value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `for`-loop syntax needs to be fixed.

The first option is to use a custom function:

```
 for (i=2; i <= 30; i = foo(i)) { ... }
```

where `foo` is a function which takes the current value of `i` and returns the next value. You will need to come up with a proper definition of `foo` yourself.

The other approach can be to put all these values in an array and use the array as indices:

```
 int indices[ MAX_INDICES ] = { 2, 6, ... };
 for (size_t j = 0; j < MAX_INDICES; ++j) { 
      /* instead of using 'j' use indices[ j ] now on */
 }
```

Comment: The second approach is better for a few reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The amount you want to add seems not to be allways the same. Because of that I would suggest to put the Values into an array and loop through it with an index.

pseudocode:

```
int vals[10];

// fill the values
vals[0] = 2;
vals[1] = 6;
vals[2] = 8;
...
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   // work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you want to put the indices in an array:

```
static const int indices[] = { 2,6,8,12,16,20,22,26,34 };
for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0]); ++i) {
    const int j = indices[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any pattern for the values of i? If not, and the number of possible values you need is small enough, you would need to create an array and the iterate across the array, something like:

```
int myValue[9] = {2,6,8,12,16,20,22,26,34};
int i;
for(i=0; i < 9; i++)
{
    printf("myValue[%d] = %d\n", i, myValue[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a step of 2 you can make it like this.
for (i=2,i<=30,i+=2) {

}

Comment: Read with more attention the question

Answer (score 0):

What are the exact constraints? Seems to increment by 4 most of the time but then there are variations.

Given that, it seems the best approach would be to put the values you need into an array and use them that way, or alternatively define a function that can generate these values and then access them that way (rather than indexing through your array of values).

Also, note the parts inside the `for`-loop are separated by `;` not `,`